# Receive notification when an item added to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, notifications

How to receive notification when an item added to recyclerview?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final OrdersData order = mUsers.get(position);
    final String client_Id = order.getClient_id();
    title = order.getItems();
    text = order.getF_name();
    holder.title.setText(order.getItems());
    holder.subtitle.setText(order.getF_name());
    holder.timeStamp.setText(order.getDateStamp());
    holder.address.setText(order.getAddress());
    String no = String.valueOf(position);
    holder.orderNo.setText(no);

}
```

Comment: Use AdapterDataObserver on adapter and send notification onChanged.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want when i add a new item in recyclerview . my device show me notification that you have one new item

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can build a local notification. In your case, I will recommend the simplest way possible. Just by calling buildLocalNotification() function right before you add data to **RecyclerView** & then notify data changed in **RecyclerView**.

```
  private void buildLocalNotification(String title, String message) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BaseActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        /**
         * Since Android Oreo
         */

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            createNotificationChannel(channelId, notificationManager);

        }

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void createNotificationChannel(String channelId, NotificationManager notificationManager) {


        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();
        assert notificationManager != null;
        if (AppConstants.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_SOUND_URI != null) {
            channel.setSound(AppConstants.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_SOUND_URI, att);
        }
        channel.setLightColor(Color.parseColor("#F1E605"));
        channel.setVibrationPattern(VIBRATE_PATTERN);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
```

Comment: well thanks for your response but i also have a notification method but i dont know how to attach it with recyclerview

Comment: It depends on how you are updating a recyclerview. Tell me your case like how you are updating a recyclerview item?

Comment: well am adding items in recyclerview through a edittext , and the whatever i enter in edittext saves in recycler item . and i want when recyclerview get a new item, device shows me a notification that 1 new item added

Comment: When you submit data from edittext you should
1. Add your new data to your array list.
2. Call buildNotificationMethod("New Data Added Title", editText.getText().toString()) 
3. Notifiy dataset changed in recyclerview.

And no recyclerview attachment required because we already have the data & can build a notification from activity/fragment. Here recyclerview is totally unknown about how we build notification & TADA we got notification ;-D